# New Laravel Project adding multiple tables with foreign keys at once

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I started a new laravel application running 5.6 and to stream-line the process I created multiple migrations at once before running migrate.
I have tons of foreign keys for linking to make my database easily scalable.

My problem is trying to reference foreign keys in databases that come later in the migration. I believe it isn't working because the tables that I'm trying to reference aren't created yet in the order of operations.

Ex:
`create_users_table` migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('password');

$table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

$table->integer('type_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
$table->foreign('type_id')->references('type_id')->on('types');

$table->integer('post_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('post_id')->on('posts');

$table->rememberToken();
$table->timestamps();
```

Ex: `create_types_table` migration:

```
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('type');

            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users')->nullable();

            $table->integer('revenue_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('revenue_id')->references('revenue_id')->on('revenue')->nullable();

            $table->integer('hours_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('hours_id')->references('hours_id')->on('hours')->nullable();

            $table->integer('project_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('project_id')->on('projects')->nullable();

            $table->integer('type_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');
            $table->timestamps();
```

I follow this same type of pattern throughout all of my tables. 
I guess my question is; is this because the tables aren't created yet so there's nothing to reference? Is there a way around this or do I need to restart, create all the tables and then add another migration for each and every table to add in foreign keys?

This could be a stupid question, I'm fairly newish to laravel. This is my first time trying to add relationships this early into an application.

Comment: You can do multiple migrations, or you can break your migration into multiple `Schema::create` / `Schema::table` blocks.

Comment: You can not reference a table that hasn't been created yet. But without seeing the actual error is difficult to tell if that's the problem.

Comment: If `create_users_table` runs before `create_types_table`, you will definitely receive an error for referencing a table that doesn't exist (`types`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign keys and their relationships cannot be nullable, make sure you remove the `->nullable()`:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```

Plus you are placing the foreign key relationship on both tables which is wrong unless you have a many to many relationship [Learn more about it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).

### When building relationships:

1. The foreign key and primary key must be identical(`increments()` means it is an Integer, unsigned, and auto-incremented).
2. You cannot do a relationship with a table that doesn't exist(in **Laravel** when you run the `php artisan migrate` it reads the migrations from oldest to newest [by date created]).
3. The `$table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');` in the `Users` table reference it to the primary key of the `Types` table which I assume is `id` laravel default when you create a new migration.

This means when it runs:

```
$table->integer('type_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('type_id')->references('type_id')->on('types');
```

It is trying to reference `type_id` column which you have just created with column `type_id` in `types` table, in this case which it doesn't exist, because it is starting with the create_users_table migration.

**My solution:**
Remove all the relationships from all the tables, only create the column that will be the foreign key like, `$table->unsignedInteger('type_id');`
run `php artisan make:migration create_foreign_keys` in the terminal, open it then place in it:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');
});
Schema::table('types', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('whatever_id')->references('id')->on('whatever_table');
});
// ....
```

This way you create all the tables, then assign the foreign keys in a separate 
migration.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot reference a table that hasn't been created yet. You can do separate `Schema::create`/`Schema::table` (as @ceejayoz said) to achieve this so all your configuration laid on a single migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
        // the rest of the fields
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('some-other-table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('other_table_id');
        // the rest of the fields
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('some-other-table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('some_field_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot reference a non existent table, you could try creating all the tables initally with no attributes eg. :

```
Schema::create('table1', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('table1_id');
    $table->int('table1_int');
});
Schema::create('table2', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('table2_id');
    $table->int('table2_int');
});
Schema::create('table3', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('table3_id');
    $table->int('table3_int');
});
```

Then later you can assign foreign key constraints and relationships eg :

```
Schema::table('table2', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('some_field_id')->references('table1_id')->on('table1');
});
Schema::table('table3', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('some_field_id')->references('table2_id')->on('table2');
});
```